# Changing activity in Android Studio (Firebase)

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-authentication

Following [this](https://youtu.be/q09NTbITV9Y?t=13m22s) tutorial (13m22s).

His if switches from the MainActivity to the StartActivity. Mine doesn't?

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        mAuth = com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(currentUser == null) {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: u mean startactivity to main?

Comment: @PeterHaddad, no. The app checks if the user is logged in and (since there's only one option; null) sends it to the StartActivity. The MainActivity will be the chat page later on. StartActivity is the register/login page.

Comment: OK, I needed to switch the MA and SA in the if statement. However, I'm getting a new error?

    error: not an enclosing class: MainActivity

I just changed the code to:

    Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);

Comment: Found the issue. Wrong Activity. My bad.